# Want to save particular node into the Xml File using c#

Tags: c#, xml

1. code below:

   ```
   protected void generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
       doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
       doc.Load("XmlFileName");
       XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("ChartData/XaxisFields/XaxisField");
       if (node != null)
       {
           node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerXml = "hi";
           doc.Save("XmlFileName");
       }

    }
   ```
2. Showing null refernce here,

   ```
   node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerXml = "hi";
   ```
3. Is the code is correct,the code behind running not showing any error
   but the Xaxisfield is not added.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <ChartData>
     <XaxisFields>
       <XaxisField></XaxisField>
     </XaxisFields>
   </ChartData>
   ```
4. List item

I want to add the childnode Xaxisfield in the xml file by selcting the particular parent node

Comment: where in your XML is there any data values..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to select your node and update its value:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("XmlFileName");
xdoc.Root.Element("XaxisFields").Element("XaxisField").Value = "hi";
// OR
// xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//XaxisField").Value = "hi";
xdoc.Save("XmlFileName");
```

Also your code is not working because there is no child nodes of `XaxisField` node. This will work:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.Load("XmlFileName");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("ChartData/XaxisFields/XaxisField");
if (node != null)
{
    node.InnerXml = "hi";
    doc.Save("XmlFileName");
}
```